# Hetzner server installimage - 4 disks, raid 1 with two of them

Tags: raid, hetzner

The following problem I have 4 disks on my Hetzner server (because cheaper dont ask)

[image]

I want Raid 1 with the most space possible. For easier setup I'm first trying 2x2TB ignoring the other 2 disks for now but not even that is working with this config:

```
DRIVE1 /dev/nvme0n1
DRIVE2 /dev/nvme1n1

SWRAID 1
SWRAIDLEVEL 1

BOOTLOADER grub

HOSTNAME Debian-1013-buster-64-minimal

PART swap swap 2G
PART /boot ext3 1024M
PART /     ext4 all

IMAGE /root/images/Debian-1013-buster-64-minimal.tar.gz
```

Can someone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: How about you tell us what is not working. PS I would use BTRFS as filesystem and use its RAID functionality

Comment: [hetzner](https://docs.hetzner.com/de/robot/dedicated-server/raid/software-raid/) has a nice tutorial how to solve the common issue. already at this point would lead the question to be offtopic due missing research

Comment: Thx you helped me with the hetzner link. In my defense stuff like this is not apparent for newbies with installimage: "If an OS is installed and software RAID is activated on the server, then just running installimage and installing a new OS without software RAID won't work. The server won't boot in this case." Why didn't they simply integrate the removing of existing software raids in the script? I got it to work now with above config, after manually removing the software raid and manually formatting all disks before running the script again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself thanks to djdomi's comment, maybe someone else can save some time like this.

Hetzner didn't include removing an activated software raid and cleaning up the disk before doing the installs in their installimage script for whatever reason, so if you run the script multiple times to test configurations, you get into trouble:

"If an OS is installed and software RAID is activated on the server, then just running installimage and installing a new OS without software RAID won't work. The server won't boot in this case."

https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/raid/software-raid

After manually cleaning up the disks and running the script again it worked with above config.